# How to attribute a named graph whose name points to something else

Tags: graph, dataset, sparql, rdf, named

Say I have a graph named `<https://paris.com>`, containing triples from my last trip to Paris. I'm aware that this is not a great way to name a graph but it is legal. It also is not uncommon that the graph name refers to something else than the graph it names, like its date of creation, its topic etc.
Now I'd like to state that this graph was created in 2021. Obviously neither Paris, the city, nor the website that the IRI dereferences to, were created in 2021, so just adding `<https://paris.com> :created 2021` wouldn't easily irritate a human reader too much. But it still would be wrong, and not easy to disambiguate for a machine.
Is there a best practice or even standard way to unambiguously address the graph so poorly named? Like some concatenation of the DataSet IRI and the graph name, or the SPARQL endpoint plus the graph name, so that I could write something like `<https://my.sparql.com/endpoint?graph=paris.com> :created 2021`? Or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store HTTP Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/) specification provides the answer to my question. In [Section 4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/#indirect-graph-identification) it explains how an URI naming a named graph can be added as a query parameter to the URI of a SPARQL endpoint to unambiguously reference that named graph. The query parameter in question is called `graph`. IIUC the URI that I used in the example to illustrate my problem above, `<https://my.sparql.com/endpoint?graph=paris.com>`, was already quite close to being the correct solution. However, the URI naming the graph has to be provided in full and percent encoded. The resulting statement that correctly encodes the example from my question would then be:

```
<https://my.sparql.com/endpoint?graph=https%3A//paris.com> :created 2021 .
```